# copy 3 newest files in remote server using expect the close the session

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

For starters, I'm a complete novice with expect scripts. I have written a few ssh scripts but I cant seem to figure out how to get the latest 3 log files after running a set of tests for a new build. My main goal is to find the latest log files and copy them to my local machine. PLEASE DON'T tell me that it's bad practice to hard code the login and password, I'm doing so because it's temporary to make the script work. My code currently...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 15

set prompt {\]\$ ?#}

spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" "root@remote_ip"
expect {
    "RSA key fingerprint" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    "assword:" {send "password\r"; exp_continue}

}
sleep 15
send -- "export DISPLAY=<display_ip>\r"
sleep 5
send "cd /path/to/test/\r"
sleep 5
set timeout -1
send "bash run.sh acceptance.test\r"
#Everything above all works. The tests has finished, about to cp log files
send "cd Log\r"
sleep 5
send -- "pwd\r"
sleep 5
set newestFile [send "ls -t | head -3"]
#tried [eval exec `ls -t | head -3`]
#No matter what I try, my code always gets stuck here. Either it wont close the session 
#or ls: invalid option -- '|' or just nothing and it closes the session.
#usually never makes it beyond here :(
expect $prompt
sleep 5
puts $newestFile
sleep 5
send -- "exit\r"
sleep 5
set timeout 120
spawn rsync -azP root@remote_ip:'ls -t /logs/path/ | head -3' /local/path/
expect {
        "fingerprint" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue};
        "assword:" {send "password\r"; exp_continue};
       }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you need `\r` in the line `send "ls -t | head -3"` ?

Comment: yes i do, thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing an expect script, you need to follow the pattern of `expect`ing the remote side to write some output (e.g., a prompt) and then `send`ing something to it in reply. The overall pattern is `spawn`, `expect`, `send`, `expect`, `send`, …, `close`, `wait`. If you don't `expect` from time to time, there are some buffers that fill up, which is probably what's happening to you.

Let's fix the section with the problems (though you should be expecting the prompt before this too):

```
send "cd Log\r"
expect -ex $prompt
send -- "pwd\r"
expect -ex $prompt
send "ls -t | head -3\r"
# Initialise a variable to hold the list of files produced
set newestFiles {}
# SKIP OVER THE LINE "TYPED IN" JUST ABOVE
expect \n
expect {
    -re {^([^\r\n]*)\r\n} {
        lappend newestFiles $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    -ex $prompt
}
# Prove what we've found for demonstration purposes
send_user "Found these files: \[[join $newestFiles ,]\]\n"
```

I've also made a few other corrections. In particular, `send` has no useful result itself, so we need an `expect` with a regular expression (use the `-re` flag) to pick out the filenames. I like to use the other form of the `expect` command for this, as that lets me match against several things at once. (I'm using the `-ex` option for exact matching with the prompts because that works better in my testing; *you might need it, or might not.*)

Also, make sure you use `\r` at the end of a line sent with `send` or the other side will be still be waiting “for you to press <kbd>Return</kbd>” which is what the `\r` simulates. And don't forget to use:

```
exp_internal 1
```

when debugging your code, as that tells you *exactly* what expect is up to.

Comment: It works! I just don't understand "$expect_out(1,string)". What exactly does that do?

Comment: According to `expect` manual: *Upon matching a pattern (or `eof` or `full_buffer`), any matching and previously unmatched output is saved in the variable `expect_out(buffer)`.  Up to `9` regexp substring matches are saved in the variables `expect_out(1,string)` through `expect_out(9,string)`.*